# Using Entity-Framework with Sqlite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6.1

I'm trying to use `Sqlite` with my `C# Console App` but when trying to add the `Entity-Framwork data model` I get the following message:

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. If you have already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit the wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action.

Steps to reproduce:

- Add a new `.NET 4` `Console Application`
- Install the `System.DataBase.SQLite (x86/x64) Nuget package` (which automatically installs the `Entity-Framwork` package as a dependency)
- Add an `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` with the Add new item dialog

after following the above steps the following `app.config` was created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <!--
        NOTE: The extra "remove" element below is to prevent the design-time
              support components within EF6 from selecting the legacy ADO.NET
              provider for SQLite (i.e. the one without any EF6 support).  It
              appears to only consider the first ADO.NET provider in the list
              within the resulting "app.config" or "web.config" file.
    -->
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

and the following `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.94.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.94.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.94.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.94.1" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Comment: What you have done only enables code first development. You need to install the SQLIte VS tools as well, download from system.data.sqlite.org

Comment: I'm looking for the appropriate download but couldn't find it. could you please point to the right direction (`VS 2013`, `.NET 4.0`)?

Comment: Name of download is sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.94.0.exe  on http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Answer (score 0):

You only need these packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.94.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.94.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

And then set you build configuration to x86!

Comment: I see these packages are for `net45`. are they also good for a `net40` project?

Comment: Updated my reply just now

Answer (score 0):

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />-->
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SettingContext" connectionString="Data Source=setting.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
```

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />

</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```